# datagridview all cell values pass to label

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
               if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
                    return;

                string id, name, price, desc, quan;
                id = dgvWarp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "";
                name = dgvWarp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + "";
                price = dgvWarp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value + "";
                desc = dgvWarp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value + "";
               // quan = dgvWarp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value + "";

                label2.Text = id;
                label3.Text = name;
                label4.Text = price;
                label5.Text = desc;
}
```

Here is my cell click event handler code.But this code not fired which i need.Actually i want datagridview cell values pass to label automatically.if i entered values in some cells only pass data to label remains blank,if i enterd all cells show all labels as per images
[image]

only 1st rows shows the values,if i entered 1st column 2nd row cell (test2)then it will shows 
test2 in place of test1.
this is my problem

Comment: Please include your entire click handler - what you've posted doesn't include the method signature. Additionally, please be more specific about what's not working with it - what do you mean by "this code not fired"?

Comment: The `Code Snippet` option is only for web languages.

Comment: Have you definitely hooked it up to the event? Either in the designer or in code?

Comment: if button click event let me the code for my need.

Comment: Could anybody help me.i need it.

Comment: @Varta yes I can but, I really dont understand what is the problem you are getting.

Comment: Dear Shell,Please see my updated one more image for my problem

Comment: @Varta have u read my answer if you have any doubt feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Give the lable name according to Row and Column index. ie. `lblRow0Col0, lblRow0Col1, lblRow1Col2` etc.

then write the following code in CellValidating Event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    String lblName = String.Format("lblRow{0}Col{1}", e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
    Label lbl = (TextBox)this.Controls[lblName];
    lbl.Text = e.FormattedValue.ToString();
}
```